# Trying to register commands: DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access

Tags: javascript, discord

Following this; https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#command-deployment-script

I'm trying to run `node deploy-commands.js` to register my commands to a single guild and I'm getting the following error.

```
    C:\Users\\\\hello-world-discord-bot>node deploy-commands.js
DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\\\\\hello-world-discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.js:198:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\\\\\hello-world-discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.js:99:20)
    at async C:\\\\\hello-world-discord-bot\deploy-commands.js:17:3 {
  rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
  code: 50001,
  status: 403,
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/877359061669118003/guilds/447125601757691915/commands'
}
```

I've tried removing the bot and re-permissioning it via the developer web console before re-adding it. I've checked and re-added the `token` `clientId` and `guildId` and I get the same error message every time. I can see it's not getting access but I've no idea where else access would be granted from.

My `deploy-commands.js` looks like this:

```
{
    "clientId": "123456789012345678",
    "guildId": "876543210987654321",
    "token": "my-token-goes-here"
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Have you made sure that the 'applications.commands' scope is checked in the scopes section of the OAuth2 settings for your bot in the discord developer portal?

Comment: I had not! The guide I'm following only mentions "bot" and "admin" I assumed it got 'everything' from those, thank you so much! I'll pay more attention to those!

Comment: i have checked that scope too but still not work after all.

Comment: @isekaimaou Have you re-invited your bot with the new authorization link?

Comment: yes, i did that at all but still get "Missing access"

Comment: i have that thing on in my case, but its still not working

Comment: The REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT, option must be checked? When I used this option I couldn't add the bot on the server, the invite went ok, but no error, just the bot doesn't enter the server.

Comment: @Danielr Apologies, I'm not sure how that is related to application commands working, nor what your issue is exactly? If you're attempting to turn off requiring OAuth2 Code Grant for your bot, go to the 'Bot' section of your bot and turn off the second toggle, which should be labeled 'REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT'.

Comment: @jh316 thanks for the reply, I solved reading the doc, it was missing my webserver ‍♂️

Comment: Also be sure the bot is invited on the corresponding guild Id provide in your config.json file.

Answer (score 16):

jh316's answer works with the additional context, for us noobs, that checking that box also requires copying the URL, pasting it in a browser so that you can access the authentication page where you get to choose the Discord server the authorization will apply to...and then click 'Authorize' in order to complete the authorization.  Then running the deploy-commands.js script will run successfully.

Comment: Do we need to do this every time we update a command?!

Comment: @L23P This procedure is a one time effort aimed at configuring permissions for the bot.  Once you set this permission, the bot is able to respond to commands.

Comment: another key point I think is missing is that you need to delete the bot user prior to running the URL for access again. (at least thats' what I experienced being the difference)

Answer (score 8):

Although I had checked ***'applications.commands'*** it would still not work for me.

The solution was quite simple,
I had copied the id of a text channel when I should have copied the **server's** id.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled into this error, in my case the issue was **guildId** being a number and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

If some one has the related problem =>
1/ Check your developer Page if the Plugin 'applications.commands' at OAuth2 settings checked!
2/ If still not work, just re-invite the bot and haveit "USE SLASH COMMANDS" Permission!