# As I am trying to finish my discord music bot I get an error that I couldn't find out what is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

When I try to load slash commands to index.js I get an error I tried to find out whats wrong but I couldn't. I am calling help you can find my codes in [here.](https://gist.github.com/FRISADO1/513016d15a5d142045fd8f4ae58e4315)

```
PS C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\Rayman Music> node index.js load
Deploying slash commands
DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\Rayman Music\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:708:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\Rayman Music\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:511:14) {
  rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
  code: 50001,
  status: 403,
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/849610614481223690/guilds/846815966540857375/commands',
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to register commands: DiscordAPIError\[50001\]: Missing Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886388/trying-to-register-commands-discordapierror50001-missing-access)

Comment: uh I checked it but I think thats not the problem I have. I think I wrote something wrong in the codes thats why.